# Error while creating an instance of an HTTP client: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: reactjs, axios

This code is a JavaScript module that uses the Axios library to create an instance of an HTTP client. The code exports this instance as axiosFetch for use in other parts of the application.

I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRq5Z.png) error in console of browser

Here is my code of axiosFetch.js
Essentially, this code sets up a preconfigured Axios instance that includes the Authorization header with a Bearer token. The value of the token is obtained from the "Authorization" item in the local storage, assuming it exists.

```
const axios = require("axios");
let access_token =
  (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? (localStorage.getItem("Authorization") ||
    window.localStorage.getItem("Authorization")) : null

let token = JSON.parse(access_token)?.token;
console.log(token);
const axiosFetch  = axios.default.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
});

export default axiosFetch;
```

What can be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')" suggests that axios.default is undefined. This is likely because you're using require to import axios, but then trying to access axios.default, which doesn't exist.

In CommonJS modules (which is the module system used by Node.js and by extension, require), the default export is not special - it's just like any other export. So when you require a module, you get an object with all the exports, and there's no default property unless the module specifically exports one.

Axios does not have a default export. Instead, the axios function itself is exported. So you should be able to create an instance of axios like this:

```
const axios = require("axios");

let access_token =
  typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? localStorage.getItem("Authorization") ||
      window.localStorage.getItem("Authorization")
    : null;
let token = JSON.parse(access_token)?.token;

console.log(token);

const axiosFetch = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});

module.exports = axiosFetch;
```

I've replaced axios.default.create with axios.create, which should fix the error.

Comment: it says axios.create is not a function

Comment: The error "axios.create is not a function" typically occurs when axios is not properly imported or installed. If you're using a version of Node.js that supports ES6 import syntax, you could try using import instead of require:

import axios from 'axios';